# JSoup & URL non Latin Charsets

Tags: character-encoding, jsoup

I am using the next implementation for Java Servlet -

String url = "http://mydomain.com/test.php?myparam="+myname;

```
Document doc = null;

try {

    doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

} catch (IOException e) {

    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

    e.printStackTrace();

}
```

Where myname is a String in UTF Charset.
For some reason the result received is not OK (unreadable chars).

Is there a way to force the URL in JSoup to be UTF as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
url = URLEncoder.encode("http://mydomain.com/test.php?myparam="+myname, "UTF-8")
```